# Dictionary operations on a dataframe column containing dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

One of my dataframe `df1` has a column `WR` with a dictionary in every row -

```
WR

----

{'M-NET':1, 'C-VTR':2, 'I-INK':9}

{'H-NKG':6, 'M-NET':2, 'C-VTR':2}

{'N-NOC':7, 'I-INK':4}

{'L-TKP':4, 'C-VTR':3, 'H-NKG':3, 'M-NET':9}

{'M-NET':1, 'C-VTR':4}
```

How can I do dictionary operations on this row. For eg. I want to make another column that contains the number of keys in each row of `WR`. Or, I want to get a sum of all the values of this dictionary.

I've tried -

```
df1['WR#'] = df1['WR'].apply(lambda x: len(x.to_dict().values()))
```

and

```
df1['WR#'] = len(df1['WR'].str.split(', '))
```

but these didn't work for me.

I need a column `WR#` that gives me

```
3
3
2
4
2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the length try with

```
df['WR'].str.len()
0    3
1    3
2    2
3    4
4    2
dtype: int64
```

If you need the `sum`

```
pd.DataFrame(df['WR'].tolist()).sum(1)
0    12.0
1    10.0
2    11.0
3    19.0
4     5.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi @Wen-Ben! The first statement gives me very high values, eg. `172, 143, 129` etc. when I know that they should all be less than 52. So, I'm guessing it gives me a character count. The second statement just returns the same column `WR` again.

Comment: @harry04 then that is not dict it is string , so do `import ast ; df['WR']=df['WR'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`